# Tcpdump stops capturing wifi data while running in the background

Tags: wifi, network-monitoring, tcpdump, background

I have a problem capturing wifi data using `tcpdump` while running in the background.

OK, lets get some facts:

- my wifi-device is named `wlan0`
- `wlan0` is in monitor mode (that's what I want)
- I'm using `tcpdump` to capture packets

If I run my script manually in the shell, it works well. Now I want to capture all packets over a long period. I decided to put my script into `/etc/rc.local` which is executed at the system-start.

It looks like this:

```
tcpdump -l -i wlan0 | do_some_action.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

After a reboot I can see that all the data captured is being forwarded to my script. So far - so good.

30-60 minutes later no data is captured anymore. `tcpdump` is still running, but `wlan0` seems to be gone sleeping.

I have to `ifdown` / `ifup` `wlan0` to get some traffic again.

Could anybody explain whats going on here and how to fix this problem?

Comment: It might be worth redirecting STDERR to a file rather than `/dev/null`.  There might be some useful information in the error messages.  Or maybe redirect the STDERR from the `tcpdump` command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried to remove the redirects. There was no info- or error output at all.

Comment: do you see any logs in /var/log/messages related to wlan0 after you start the capture ?

Comment: Relating to wlan0 there is only one entry. This is okay i think. `kernel: device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode`